# How to call a function within a function?

Tags: c++, function, compiler-construction, reverse, palindrome

I am trying to determine if my code is a palindrome so I created a reverse function and then a palindrome function. I am trying to assign the reversed Character array into the new function but I can't seem to get it to compile.... any tips?
Here is my palindrome function

```
bool Palindrome(char Characters[], unsigned long length)
{
   char tempstring[62];
   tempstring[62] == reverse(Characters);

   for(int i=0; i <= length; i++){
      if(Characters[i] == tempstring[i])
          return false;
      else
          return true;
   }

}
```

Here is my reverse function

```
void reverse(char Characters[], unsigned long length)
{
    char temp;   

    for(int i=0; i<length/2; i++){
        temp = Characters[i];
        Characters[i]=Characters[length-i-1];
        Characters[length-i-1]=temp;

    }
}
```

Comment: Your main problem is that you are trying to assign a value to tempstring[62] even though the reverse function is a void (does not return anything). Just follow Ed Heal's answer and you will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making this quite complicated.

Just find the end of the string (`strlen`). Read from both ends a character at a time and if they do not match then it is not a palindrome. If the indexes become the same or they cross then you are done. It is indeed a palindrome.

I.e

```
bool Palindrome(char *s) {
   int left = 0, right = strlen(s) - 1;
   while (left < right) {
      if (s[left] != s[right] return false;
      ++left;
      --right;
   }
   return true;
}
```

**EDIT**

Similar vain to construct the reverse

```
char *Reverse(char *s)
{
    char *rev = new char[strlen(s) + 1];
    int left = 0, right = strlen(s) - 1;
    while (right > -1) {
       rev[left] = s[right];
       right--;
       left++;
    }
    rev[left] = 0;
    // Remember to use delete[]
    return rev;
 }
```

**EDIT 2**

Or

```
void Reverse(char[] s, int len) {
   int left = 0; right = len;
   while (right > -1) {
      char t = s[left];
      s[left] = s[right];
      s[right] = t;
      left++; right--;
   }
}
```

Then make a copy of the string, reverse it and compare it.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I want to be able to figure it out using another function, its just practice is all and wanted to know what I was doing wrong? Because I also call that same reverse function in my main a few times. @ed heal

Comment: It would be an acceptable answer without the first edit "Remember to use delete"

Comment: @DieterLücking - he wanted a reverse function. The first part is the better solution

Comment: @EdHeal A function returning something new is usually no good (besides allocators etc etc)

Comment: @DieterLücking Can't you just use malloc or dynamic memory allocation, which would be pretty much the same thing, just not as efficient?

Comment: @user3078582 Please do not go that path to memory leaks

Answer (score 5):

First things first, you have a typo; `==` is a compare equality, `=`. You ought to have written

`tempstring[62] = reverse(Characters);`

**But this will still not work**. For starters, `reverse` is a `void` function and so therefore it does not return a value.

The quickest fix will be to replace that line with

```
reverse(Characters, length);
```

(Note that I'm also passing the `length` parameter as required).

One final thing: if you have organised your file so that `reverse` appears after `Palindrome`, then you need to *forward declare* `reverse` using this statement:

```
void reverse(char Characters[], unsigned long length);
```

That fixes the compilation errors. I defer to you to check the runtime behaviour.

Comment: @bathseba what about the length not being called?

Comment: @DieterLücking: Apologies for the incomplete answer. I've addressed that now.

Comment: @user3078582: I've edited to give a more comprehensive answer.

Comment: You still suggest (even you mention: it will not work) `tempstring[62] = reverse(Characters);`

Comment: Yeah it's a tough one to answer: You do want to point out the difference between == and = even though neither do what you want in this instance. Hopefully bold type goes some way to address that.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is the line `tempstring[62] == reverse(Characters);`. You don't need the double = sign. In the future, it would be helpful to post the error messages you get when compiling.

```
bool Palindrome(char Characters[], unsigned long length)
{
   char tempstring[62];
   tempstring[62] = reverse(Characters);

   for(int i=0; i <= length; i++){
      if(Characters[i] == tempstring[i])
          return false;
      else
          return true;
   }

}
```

Comment: When I do this, I also must declare length, since length is in the prototype of reverse, which gives me this error        In function ‘bool Palindrome(char*, long unsigned int)’:
Reversal2.cpp:97:19: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
    tempstring[62] = reverse(Characters, length);

Comment: Your `reverse` function is declared as `void`, yet you're expecting it to return a value to be stored in `tempstring`. You're also walking off the end of the `tempstring` array by trying to assign a value to index 62. Valid indices are from 0 to 61.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is here:

```
tempstring[62] == reverse(Characters);
```

You've wrote `==` means, a condition that returns true or false (for example: `if (5 == 7)` -> false)

But what you've actually wanted to do was `tempstring[62] = reverse(Characters);`

One `=` means equal (`int a = 3`)

Two `==` means to check a condition (for example `if (a == b)` (and thats why you dont write in ifs: `if(a = 3)` because it will assign `a = 3` and allways get inside the `if`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your reverse function returns nothing, so attempting to assign its return value to anything is not going to work:

```
tempstring[62] == reverse(Characters); // won't work as it is attempting to compare a void
tempstring[62] = reverse(Characters); // won't work as it is attempting to assign a void
```

From a more fundamental level, testing for a palindrome is much less complex than you are making it:

```
bool Palindrome(char Characters[], unsigned long length)
{
    bool result = true;
    for(int i=0; i < length / 2; i++)
    {
        if (Characters[i] != Characters[length - i - 1])
        {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```